# Why is deque so quick?

Tags: python

I was doing some work with deque which my friend taught me 1 day ago ( the same friend who had me do the int wihtout inting problem). But anyways, i noticed deque seemed to be incredibly fast so I wrote some code comparing deque finding the median by removing 1 by 1 to a standard list removing 1 by 1. In the test, deque finished in 0.09 seconds while a standard list took 89 seconds. I don't get why deque is so much faster since at the end of the day both deque and a standard list are removing elements from a sorted list 1 by 1 so it should have the same runtime. Could someone please tell me how deque works and why it's so fast? NOTE: The list below has been greatly shrotened from 79,360 elements long to 1052 to comply with Stack Overflow's character limit. If you want to recreate the list I did, copy and paste the elements in the list around 80 times. Sorry for the incovience in advance.

```
from collections import deque as d
from time import time as t

#ignore this part
inp = [3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24,1,2,4,3,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,5,432,1,4,52,432,35,2,3,5,2,34,5,2,23,5,34,5,2,3,34,52,53,25,2,3,45,235,2,5,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,2,45,5,32,5,43,255,325,32,3,5,235,42,5,1,24]
print(len(inp))

# here's the important code
inp.sort()
# use deque
st1 = t()
def convert(inp):
    return d(inp)

converted = convert(inp)

def wompwomp(inp):
    while len(inp) > 2:
        inp.pop()
        inp.popleft()

    if len(inp) == 2:
        return (inp[0] + inp[1])/2
    else:
        return inp[0]

print(wompwomp(converted))
et1 = t()

tim1 = et1 - st1
print(f" Time is {tim1}")


# standard
st2 = t()


while len(inp) > 2:
    inp.remove(inp[0])
    inp.remove(inp[-1])
if len(inp) == 2:
    inp = (inp[0] + inp[1])/2
else:
    pass

et2 = t()
tim2 = et2 - st2
print(f"Time is {tim2}")
print(str(inp))
```

Comment: `deque`s (double-ended queue) are optimized for operations at its ends. When you remove an item from the beginning of a list, it has to reindex all the subsequent elements (making it O(n)). A deque doesn't have that problem and both pop and popleft are O(1) operations. However, `deque`s also use more memory. [This may help answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33261762/5747944).

Comment: "... it has to reindex all the subsequent elements ..." - To be more precise, it *moves* the subsequent elements.  That operation is `O(N)` in time where `N` is the number of elements after the one you removed from the list.  And if you remove from the start of the list, `N` is the current list size.

Comment: @sytech Yes that solves it thanks. Im curious why this didn't appear when I googled searched but that's besides the point. From what im getting, deques removing items at the end of it is O(1) while lists are O(n) because they have to shift the 1st element to the 0th 2nd to 1st, etc etc, and O(1) is much faster than O(n) which makes it infinitely faster than standard lists correct?

Comment: *"NOTE: The list below has been greatly shortened from 79,360 elements long to 1052 to comply with Stack Overflow's character limit."* - You could have generated a random list ... or indeed any list at all.  The cost of adding and removing to a list or deque doesn't depend on the element values.  (And your sorting step is not needed for this test either.)