# delete the hashed node in deque in O(1)

Tags: python, deque, python-internals

How do I hash a built-in node in deque (which is a double linked list) and delete the node in the middle in O(1)? Is the built-in node exposed?

For example, I want to save a deque's node in dict so I can delete the node in constant time later.

This is a use case in LRU, using deque so I don't need to write my own double linked list.

```
from collections import deque

class LRU:
  def __init__(self):
    self.nodes = deque()
    self.key2node = {}

  def insertThenDelete(self):
    # insert
    node = deque.Node('k', 'v') # imagine you can expose deque node here
    self.nodes.appendleft(node) 
    self.key2node = {'k': node} 

    # delete
    self.key2node['k'].deleteInDeque() # HERE shold remove the node in DLL!
    del self.key2node['k']
```

I know you can do `del mydeque[2]` to delete by index.
but I want to do `key2node['k'].deleteInDeque()` delete by referance.

Comment: What is `deque` here? The class by that name in the built-in collections module does not have a `Node` attribute.

Comment: For that matter, the built-in deque class doesn't even have per-item nodes at all. If you're hoping to use `collections.deque`, give up and use something else.

Comment: `collections.deque` is double linked list based (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6257048/3023116), so you cannot have O(1) deletions from the middle.

Comment: @taras: You could if the list wasn't unrolled and it exposed node references, but neither of those things are the case.

Comment: @user2357112, I didn't know it. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Updated. deque.Node() is just to imagine you can expose the built-in node, to explain my idea. (I tried my best to explain. Hope it is ok.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *deque* API doesn't support direct reference to internal nodes or direct deletion of internal nodes, so what you're trying to do isn't possible with *collections.deque()*.

In addition, the deque implementation is a doubly-linked list of fixed-length blocks where a block in a array of object pointers, so even if you could get a reference, there would be no easy way to delete just part of a block (it is fixed length).

Your best bet is to create your own doubly-linked list from scratch.  See the source code for functools.lru_cache() which does exactly what you're describing:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/functools.py#L405

Hope this helps :-)