# Push front (unshift) performance in Go

Tags: go, slice

Appending an item to a slice in Go has amortized O(1) performance, since slices are backed by an array. Is this the same case for prepending an item to a slice? For example, this is usually done as follows:

```
a = append([]T{x}, a...)
```

Am I right in thinking that the elements of `a` are being copied to a new *array* here, and that this happens in O(n) time? If so, if I want to implement a deque-like data structure, would using a List be more appropriate (such as how deques are implemented [in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6257048))?

This may be a niche use case. I'm mostly asking for scenarios like coding interviews, where the time limit may be exceeded for certain test cases.

Comment: Yes, prepend is inefficient. What is more efficient in a particular usecase depends.